# Google Map JS not displaying map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

What am I missing to make this work (the address is just arbitrary).  I'm getting no firebug JS errors but it is just not showing the map. I'm using this code on another page (and it is working) so there must be something somewhere I've missed.  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
#map_canvas {
    height: 325px;
    width: 325px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  var address ="9712 West Northern Avenue Peoria,AZ 85345";
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-37.0625, 95.677068);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 11,
      center: latlng,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      panControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
                  size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
                });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map, 
                title:address
            }); 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

          } 
        } 
      });
    }
  }
</script>
 <div id="map_canvas"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it..sorry for the time waste:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```